# How to get the default shared element transition used on my phone?

Tags: android, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I'm having trouble setting up the correct transition set for my transition, but the default Shared Element Transition on my phone works perfectly. Unfortunately, it's not the same on all phones, so I want to hard code it.
After setting

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
```

I tried

```
Transition transition = getWindow().getSharedElementExitTransition();
        if(transition != null){
            System.out.println(TAG +": "+ getWindow().getSharedElementExitTransition().getName());
            if(transition instanceof TransitionSet){
                for(int i =0; i< ((TransitionSet) transition).getTransitionCount(); i++){
                    System.out.println(TAG + ": \t@" +((TransitionSet) transition).getTransitionAt(i).getName());
                }
            }
        }
```

but the transition is null. How can I get this Transition? (This is the default transition on my Google Pixel and my Moto G5S+ (with Oreo and Marshmallow respectively), so it might be safe to assume this is some sort of stock android default, and the other one is a different OEM (with Lollipop))

Some other details: I'm using this for a grid to ViewPager setup, and I tried setting `ChangeBounds()`, `ChangeImageTransform()` and a combination of both, and I set them programmatically, but they're not working as expected